# Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I don't know why I get the error in the title... I have a small piece of code:

```
Do While ws2.Cells(Rand, 1).Value <> "" And Rand < 65000
    Min = ws2.Cells(Rand, 5).Value
    Data = ws2.Cells(Rand, 1).Value
    If Min <> 0 Then
        Do Until Min = 0
            If Min < MinZi Then
                ws.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Data
                ws.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Min / MinZi
                Min = 0
            Else
                ws.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Data
                ws.Cells(lRow, 2).Value = 1
                Data = DateAdd("d", -1, Data) **'the error is on this line**
                Min = Min - MinZi
            End If
        lRow = lRow + 1
        Loop
    End If
Rand = Rand + 1
Loop
```

In ws2.Cells(Rand,1) I have some dates... so I want to read every row in ws2 as long as I have a date on it... if there is a date I'm looking for the number of minutes in column 5. 
So if the number of minutes are not equal to 0 then if the number of minutes is smaller than the number of minutes in a day I calculate how much Min represents... else if the number of minutes is bigger than the number of minutes in a day I add the date in a different worksheet with the number 1 (which means it's 100% full), then I subtract the number of minutes in a day until I have 0 minutes.
Data is defined as a Date.
Any ideas why I get this error?

**Another strange thing is that in the sheet buffer (ws) it adds as many lines as the current date is (12/14/2011 means 40891 lines) ...and I don't know why.
Any ideas?**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Andrei lon we will help you if you let us know how the values look like

Comment: I guess your Minzi variable has number of minutes ? you mean the whole day is represented with minutes by converting hours and seconds into minutes huh?

Comment: else if the number of minutes is bigger than the number of minutes in a day I add the date in a different worksheet with the number 1 (which means it's 100% full), then I subtract the number of minutes in a day . explain these sentence clearly so that i can help you

Answer (score 0):

If `Min > 0 and MinZi = 0` then the inner loop will continue until something falls over.

Possible reasons for falling over:

- If lRow is an integer, reaching the value 32767.  Error message: "Overflow".
- lRow reaching the maximum value for a row in your version of Excel.  Error message: "Application-defined or object-defined error".
- Data reaching -657434.  Error message: Invalid procedure call or arguement".

I believe your program stops on `ws.Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Data` and not on `Data = DateAdd("d", -1, Data)`.

I suggest you investigate MinZi and I suggest you pay more attention to the debugger before asking for help.